# spans are stacking on top of eachother rather than below eachother in react app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a simple editor with numbered lines. I am hard-coding the spans that will represent the line numbers for the time being, but the spans are stacking on top of each other rather than following each other vertically. What I want is for one of these spans to appear next to each line in the textarea.
Here is react typescript code

```
import React from 'react';
import './Editor.css';

const Editor = () => {
    return (
        <div className="editor">
            <textarea id="codeArea" placeholder="yo bro" />
            <span className="editorLineNumber">1</span>
            <span className="editorLineNumber">2</span>
            <span className="editorLineNumber">3</span>
            <span className="editorLineNumber">4</span>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Editor;
```

and here is css

```
.editor {
    counter-reset: line;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.editor #codeArea {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    resize: none;
    padding-left: 60px !important;
}

.editor pre {
    padding-left: 60px !important;
}

.editor .editorLineNumber {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    color: #cccccc;
    text-align: right;
    width: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Can someone help so that each subsequent span goes to the next line?
Attached is a picture for clarity. If it's not clear, the line numbers `1`-`4` are all stacked on top of each other.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `editorLineNumber` class has `position: absolute` which removes an HTML element from the normal flow and inserts it absolutely positioned relative the closest ancestor with a `position` other than `static`. In your case, the closest ancestor `editor` has `position: relative` which makes the `editorLineNumber` elements position themselves with respect to this `editor` element. Since `left: 0` is set on the `editorLineNumber` elements and nothing else is used to position them, they all end up at the top left corner of the `editor` element stacked on top of each other.

Fix it by removing `position: absolute` on `editorLineNumbers` and use `<p>` or `<div>` instead of `<span>` if you want them to appear in a column since `<span>` is an inline element which will stack horizontally as long as they can fit in a row.

Comment: When I remove `position: absolute` the column starts much lower than where the text starts. Is there a way to keep the column starting in around the same line as the first line in the textarea, and then to make each new <p>, <div>, <span>, etc. appear below the previous, about a textarea line apart?

Comment: Yes, there are very many ways to achieve this, two simple ways to start with is to either stack block level elements inside `editor`, namely using `<div>`s or `<p>`s but you might have to style them and remove margins and paddings if you think that the layout doesn't look good. Another way to do it is to use `display: flex; flex-direction: column` on `editor`, then the layout will follow the flex-box specification instead and layout the items in a vertical column. Search for these concepts on Google and you will find many useful results.

Comment: If you think they're not ending up where you want, there is some margin or padding or height / width restrictions that keep the elements from growing as much as you want. Use the development tools in the browser to inspect each element and find which one is causing your layout to not look as you intend.